# Find number of rows on each table in a schema in postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, schema, rowcount

I'm running this in Postgres 9.4 to get the number of rows on each table in a particular schema:

```
select table_schema, table_name,
       (xpath('/row/count/text()', query_to_xml('select count(*) from '||format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), true, true, '')))[1]::text::int as row_count
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'pricing'
```

It works in Postgres 9.4 but in Postgres 8.4 I get an error saying format function doesn't exist, is there a similar function in postgres 8.4?

In postgres 8.4 I get this:

> function format(unknown, information_schema.sql_identifier,
> information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the table row counts in all schema

```
SELECT relname, n_tup_ins - n_tup_del as rowcount FROM pg_stat_all_tables;
```

All the table row counts in the given schema

```
SELECT 
  nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE 
  nspname IN ('schema_name') AND
  relkind='r' 
ORDER BY reltuples DESC;
```

Comment: I think this provides estimates, doesn't?

Comment: yes it only provides estimate